# Longclick listview delete data from firebase - android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I retrieve data from fireabase to listview but only `name` that i retrieve, so i want to delete one of many data with longclickitem.

this is listview looks like :

- Manggo
- Durian
- Pineapple

When i longclick manggo, i could get the `name` also the `id`.

This is how i retrieve all data to listview.

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    model = ds.getValue(Model.class);
                    list.add(model.getNama().toString());


            }
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            sortData(ascending);
            ascending = !ascending;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This is my longclick method :

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            listItem = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Toast.makeText(RetrieveActivity.this, listItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            delFruit(listItem);

            return false;
        }

        private void delFruit(String id) {
            DatabaseReference dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Fruit").child("").child(listItem);
            dr.removeValue();

        }
    });
```

So how can i get the `id` when i longclickitem in `name` of data.

Comment: what id your taking about?onItemLongClick your currently getting position as id.

Comment: its key on firebase, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find a way to keep the `ds.getKey()` for each snapshot in the adapter, so that you can look it up when needed.

A good example of this can be found in FirebaseUI, which has a [`FirebaseArray` class](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/4b98a9853bf3cee9d0a32312ecf1897f740d1547/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java) that keeps the actual snapshots of the data in a list:

```
private final List<DataSnapshot> mSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now whenever a app that uses the FirebaseUI adapters has a situation like yours, it can look up the `DatabaseReference` or key for that item with:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    listItem = adapter.getRef(position).removeValue();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: i could not get `getRef`

Comment: That method only exists if you're using an adapter from FirebaseUI, or if you created it yourself.